# Can we say sentences like "They are so/too good of people"

Tags: sentence-structure, usage

As far as I know we can say **"He is so good a person"** for meaning **"He is a very good person**" or **"He is a person who is so good"** while we can't say **"He is a so good person"**. Also we can say **"He is too good a person"** for meaning **"He is a person who is too good"** while we can't say **"He is a too good person"**.

And again, as far as as I know, we can't say **"They are so/too good people"**. Can I say **"They are so/too good of people"** like I can say **"He is so/too good a person"**.

I mean, for meaning **"They are people who are so good"** or **"They are very good people"**, can I say **"They are so good of people"**? And for meaning **"They are people who are too good"**, can I say **"They are too good of people"**?

EDIT: I just found many results on Google for "He is **too** good a person" and "They are **too** good of people", but there are too few results for their versions with **"so"** instead of **"too"**. It seems like we can use **"too"** in those kinds of sentences, but it is wrong to use **"so"** this way. What do you think?

Comment: Basically? No. Not formally correct *or* colloquially idiomatic.

Comment: No, you can't say "of people", because "they are people", not "they are of people".

Comment: @stangdon That structure is used.

Comment: @Darael Thanks. I just found many results for "He is **too** good a person" and "They are **too** good of people", but there are too few results for their version with **"so"** instead of **"too"**. It seems like we can use **"too"** in those kinds of sentences, but it is wrong to use **"so"** this way. What do you think?

Comment: I prefer "they are such good people", or "those people are far too good" which mean different things. You seem to be asking about more than one meaning, so the question is unclear.

Comment: @Weather Vane Thank you. I have two questions for you: 1) Can I say **"They are too good of people."** for meaning **"They are people who are too good."**? 2) Can I say **"He is too good a person."** for meaning **"He is a person who is too good."**?

Comment: Still unclear whether your last comment asks 1 or 2 questions. If 2 questions, 1) we don't say it like that, whatever it is intended to mean. 2) We say "these people are do-gooders".

Comment: I don't know the technical terms, but using "so" as an adverb implies that more information is coming. For example, It's so hot outside, I saw a coyote chasing a jack rabbit and they were both walking! Occasionally it's used on it's own (e.g., You guys are so fast!), but that's very colloquial and is usually used as an emphasis indicating astonishment.

Comment: @ScottM Thank you. So, can't I say those sentences with **"so"** as an exclamation?

Comment: @FireandIce, Calling someone good usually requires some context. *How* are they good? Those people are so good to me! Or, Jenny is so good with children! Just saying that someone is "so good" in general is unusual. As Weather Vane mentioned, in that case "such good people" would be much more common. And please note that I said "occasionally" in my previous comment about using "so" on it's own. You will hear it, but it's not nearly as common as the other form. I suggest you stick with normal usage for now.

Comment: They are people who are so good. Ergo, they are such good people. The word **such** is the elephant in the room.

Answer (score 1):

You can say

> He is too good of a person to have done something like that. Are you sure it was him?
>
> He is too good a person to have done something like that. Are you sure it was him?

I hear  **too good of a {something}** a lot (Central Atlantic American English).

> It's too good of a deal to pass up.

But I haven't heard this construction used with a plural and without the singular indefinite article **a**.

> **They** are too good of **a team**. We don't stand a chance.<sup>YES</sup>
>
> They are too good **of athletes**. We don't stand a chance. <sup>NO</sup>
>
> He is too good of **an athlete**. I don't stand a chance.<sup>YES</sup>

Comment: Thanks. You can find examples on Google where it is used with plural subjects.  Also, can't I simply say **"He is too bad a person."**, **"He is too big a moron."**, **"She is too tall a girl."** etc.? Do I have to say like **"He is too short a guy to play basketball"**?

Comment: @Fire and Ice: I was editing as you were typing.

Comment: Thanks again. We can't use that construction with **"so"**, right? For example we can say **"He is too bad a person."**, but we can't say **"He is so bad a person."**, am I right?

Comment: We *can* say *He is so bad a person that I wish you were not working at his company.*

Comment: Thanks again. I have two more questions about this: 1) Can we drop **"that"** in that sentence? I think so. 2) Can't we say **"He is so bad a person"** for meaning **"He is a person who is so bad."**. I mean for saying that he is a very bad person?

Comment: This site says that we can say "He is so good a friend" https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/determiners.html I am so confused.

Comment: But the meaning is **"He is this good a friend."** there I guess.

Comment: @Fire and Ice:  Yes, you can drop **that**.  *It was so spicy a dish (that) I couldn't eat it.*

Comment: @Fire and Ice:  Native speakers in conversation will often use **so** as an intensifier to mean "very much" or "to a very great extent".  **You are *so* drunk!** or **She is *so* talented!**.  We put great emphasis on the word **so** when it is used in that manner.  **Dude, you are *so-o-o-o* lucky!**

Comment: Thanks. I know that. :) I am right about that "He is so good a friend." can't mean "He is a very good friend." but it means "He is this good a friend.", right?

Comment: @Fire and Ice:  I do not know what you mean by **this** in *He is this good a friend*.  Are you referring to something said earlier in the conversation? Such as  *He lent me his car when he really needed it himself. He is so good a friend.*  If so, the idiomatic version (at least in AmE) is **He lent me his car when he needed it himself. He is *that* good  a friend.**  Speakers might say **so** instead of **that** there, in some English-speaking places in the world. But you could say *He is so good a friend that he lent me his car when he really needed it himself.*

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the "of" would be considered very ungrammatical in British English, though I'm not sure.  I couldn't say whether it's considered correct in American English or whether it's just a very common ungrammatical usage.